# interoperability Raspberry Pi OS on any various Raspberry Pi boards

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

Raspberry Pi Imager is the quick and easy way to install Raspberry Pi OS to a microSD card, ready to use with Raspberry Pi.

This microSD card can be used on any various Raspberry Pi board versions.
[models](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings)

Can a microSD card once used on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ also be used on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and vice versa when it has been used on Pi 4 back on Pi 3? Does this matter?

And what about updates? Can updates (`sudo apt update && apt full-upgrade`) to Raspberry Pi OS be done on any model independently on which boards the card has been used before?

Comment: If your SDCard has RaspiOS 32bit from Feb 2023 it will run on any system. The 32-bit kernel on the 4B (`kernel7l.img`) is different to the 32-bit kernel used on a 3B (`kernel7img`). But the basic system should "just work". There are moves to make the 4B run the 64-bit kernel by default (`kernel8.img`) with a 64-bit user space - if you install specifically for the 4B.

Answer (score 2):

> This microSD card can be used on any various Raspberry Pi board versions.

*If* it is the 32-bit version of the OS.  The 64-bit one works only on the Pi  3 and 4.

> Can a microSD card once used on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ also be used on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and vice versa when it has been used on Pi 4 back on Pi 3?

It should be fairly easy to keep it so, although it is not impossible to do things that would make it not work or work properly, eg., by deleting kernels and/or kernel modules, or putting stuff in `/boot/config.txt` that aren't compatible on all models (the bootloader may be able to ignore these, but if you tried hard enough, you might be able to come up with something).

Different models can of course require different configurations to serve the same purpose(s).  To provide for this, you can use [conditional filters](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#conditional-filters) in `config.txt`.

> what about updates?

WRT the stuff that is necessarily different, such as the kernels, updates to the 32-bit OS include kernels, etc., for all versions regardless of what machine they run on.